# a4j:commanbutton still disabled after closing jquery dialog box

Tags: jquery, jsf-2, richfaces

Custom pop up is displayed onclick of delete button.Delete is disabled onclick.
When user click on Ok or cancel button "Delete" button is enabled after delete operation.
When X button in dialog box is clicked , dialog is closed immediately but delete button still in  disabled state.Below is my code

**Below code for button**

```
<a4j:commandButton id="btnDelete" execute="@form" value="Delete" onclick="this.disabled=true;javascript:showModalPopup('delete_popup_id','btnDelete',300);" tabindex="4" immediate="true" />
```

**showModalPopup function using jQuery to open dialog box**

/** This function is used open show modal popup */

```
function showModalPopup(popupId, popUpWidth) {
    $( "#"+popupId).dialog({
        modal: true,
        width: popUpWidth,
        resizable: false
    }); 
}
```

**code for custom pop up**

```
<div id="delete_popup_id" title="Application name" class="divOff">
   <h:form ">
   <h:outputText value="" />
   <div align="center" id="timerButtonPanel">
   <h:commandButton value="ok" action=""  />
   <h:commandButton value="cancel"/>
   </div>
   </h:form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your javascript `showModelPopup` function to :

```
function showModalPopup(popupId,popUpWidth){
    $( "#"+popupId).dialog({
        modal: true,
        width: popUpWidth,
        resizable: false,
        close: enableDeleteButton
    }); 
}
```

Add this javascript function to enable the delete button.

```
function enableDeleteButton(){
    document.getElementById('btnDelete').disabled=false;
}
```